# After success step fails to find files under project root in travis-ci build

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

My .travis.yml is (enhanced with debug commands):

```
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
install:
- gradle assemble -x signArchives
after_success:
- pwd
- ls -l
- chmod +x deploy_artifacts.sh
- ./deploy_artifacts.sh
```

The output of the after_success step is:

```
pwd
/home/travis/build/imperva/shcf4j

ls -l
total 44
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  3136 Oct 18 13:13 build.gradle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis   461 Oct 18 13:13 deploy-artifacts.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis    41 Oct 18 13:13 gradle.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  2656 Oct 18 13:13 imperva.travis.gpg.enc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 11357 Oct 18 13:13 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  1205 Oct 18 13:13 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis   387 Oct 18 13:13 settings.gradle
drwxrwxr-x 4 travis travis  4096 Oct 18 13:14 shcf4j-api
drwxrwxr-x 4 travis travis  4096 Oct 18 13:14 shcf4j-httpcomponents-client4

chmod +x deploy_artifacts.sh
chmod: cannot access â€˜deploy_artifacts.shâ€™: No such file or directory

./deploy_artifacts.sh
/home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 104: ./deploy_artifacts.sh: No such file or directory
```

I tried to troubleshoot the issue according to the travis guide with local docker builder but without success. I don't understand why the command fails to find the file: **deploy_artifacts.sh**

Full build log can be found here: https://www.travis-ci.org/imperva/shcf4j/builds/443179453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `chmod +x` on `deploy_artifacts.sh` while the file in your folder is named `deploy-artifacts.sh`.

The `_` should be a `-` and then it should work.